# Vue.js AWS-S3 : On upload content-length is incorrect

Tags: vue.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

When I want to upload file in my S3 Bucket, API return a 403 error due to the signature.
Cause is the incorrect Content-Length. My file is near 26000 and the request header incate 42000.
I don't understand why PutObjectCommand send this size.

I try :

```
import { notify } from "@kyvg/vue3-notification";
import { S3Client, PutObjectCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";

export function useS3() {
  const region = import.meta.env.SLB_S3_REGION;
  const accessKeyId = import.meta.env.SLB_S3_ACCESS_KEY;
  const secretAccessKey = import.meta.env.SLB_S3_SECRET_KEY;
  const Bucket = import.meta.env.SLB_S3_BUCKET;

  const uploadImage = async (file, fileName) => {
    try {
      console.log(file)
      const data = new Uint8Array(await file.arrayBuffer());
      console.log(data)
      const Key = `folder/${fileName}`;

      const client = new S3Client({
        region,
        credentials: {
          accessKeyId,
          secretAccessKey,
        },
      });

      await client.send(
        new PutObjectCommand({
          Bucket,
          Key,
          Body: data,
          ContentType: file.type
        })
      );
      console.log(data)

      return Key;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      notify({
        text: error.response?.data?.error?.message || error?.message,
        type: "error",
      });
      throw error;
    }
  }
  return {
    uploadImage,
  };
}
```